# some property and its solution for a cyclic-symmetric inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, cyclic-groups

Let $$ D = x_1x_2...x_{m-1} + x_1x_2...x_{m-2} + ... x_1 + 1$$
$$ S = x_1 x_2...x_m - 1 > 0 $$
and $$x_i > 0, i=1,...,m$$
For inequalities $S-D$ and its cyclic-symmetric derivatives:
$$ F(x_1, x_2, ..., x_m) = x_1x_2...x_m - x_1x_2...x_{m-1} - x_1x_2...x_{m-2} - ... x_1 - 2 < 0 \\
F(x_m, x_1, x_2, ..., x_{m-1}) = x_mx_1x_2...x_{m-1} - x_mx_1x_2...x_{m-2} - x_mx_1x_2...x_{m-3} - ... x_m - 2 < 0 \\
... \\
F(x_2, ..., x_m, x_1) = x_2...x_mx_1 - x_2...x_{m} - x_2...x_{m-1} - ... x_2 - 2 < 0 
$$
The set of its solution is:
$$M = \left\{ (x_1, ..., x_m)| F(x_1, ... , x_m) < 0, F(x_m, x_1, ...x_{m-1}) < 0, ..., F(x_2, ..., x_m, x_1) < 0 \right\} $$

Frankly speaking, I don't know how to solve the inequality $F < 0$, but here are some following properties that I found in doing so.

1. if point $P_1 = (c_1, c_2, ..., c_m) \in M$ then points $P_2 = (c_2,c_3,..., c_m, c_1), P_3, ... P_m = (c_m, c_1, ..., c_{m-1})$
   are also in set $M$.
2. Set $M'=\left\{ (x_1,...,x_m) | 0 < x_i < 2 , \prod_{i=1}^m x_i > 1 \right\} \subseteq M$

Since $F(x_1, ..., x_m) = x_1...x_{m-1}(x_m-2) + x_1...x_{m-2}(x_{m-1}-2) + ... x_1(x_2 -2) + (x_1 -2) < 0$ and $x_i > 0,$

Now my question is

- Are there any new property or any books/papers related to $F$ (or $M$) ?
- For $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_m) \in M$, $x_i$ has the same range(according to property 1), Does there exists $b>0$ such that $x_i<b, i=1,...,m$ ($x_i$ is bounded)

Comment: The statement "It is obvious to verify..." is false. So, your deduction from it can't be true either. I think you mean to say that if a point $P_1 \in M$, each point corresponding to a cyclical permutation of its coordinates is also in $M$, which is true but trivial because of the definition of $M$. Also, why go through the definitions of "S" and "D"? Why expect this $F$ is so interesting there would be papers about it?

Comment: yeah I've fixed it. I wanna know in what circumstance the fraction $$ F' = \frac{D}{S} > 1 $$ with cyclical symmetric restriction

Comment: @bruceyuan Did you look at the case $m = 2, 3$? (If so, you may write it down which is helpful.)